# How to make a search function in Django with multiple queryset?

Tags: python, django

Hi i'm having trouble with my search function, I want to get product and quantity items from DB as user inputs data in searchbar... but the problem is that im having getting no results.. any help?

views.py

```
def productsearch(request):
    try:
        product=request.GET.get['product']
        quantity=request.GET.get['quantity']
        product_result=Product.objects.filter(product_id__icontains=product)
        quantity_result=Product.objects.filter(quantity_onhand__icontains=quantity)
        return render_to_response('product/productlocation.html',{'product_result' : product_result,'quantity_result':quantity_result, 'product': product,'quantity':quantity})
    except:
        return render_to_response('product/productlocation.html')
```

template to show result

```
{% if quantity_result %}
 {% for r in quantity_result %}
{{r.quantity_onhand}} 
{% endfor %}
{% else %}
    <h3>no results</h3>
{% endif %}
```

search bar

```
 <form action="{% url 'productsearch' %}" method="get">   
        <label for="from">Product</label>
            <input type="text" name="product" value={{request.GET.product}}> <br /><br />
        <label for="to">Quantity &nbsp;</label>
            <input type="text" name="quantity" value={{request.GET.quantity}}> <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True)
    product_name=models.CharField("Product Name",max_length=50)
    product_unitprice=models.PositiveIntegerField("Unit Price")
    product_size=models.CharField("Product Size",max_length=10)
    productdetail=models.CharField("Product Detail",max_length=100)
    product_img=models.FileField()
    product_type= models.CharField(max_length=15,choices=product_choice, default='stockable')
    retailer_price=models.PositiveIntegerField()
    wholeseller_price=models.PositiveIntegerField()
    location=models.CharField("Locatiion",max_length=30)
    quantity_onhand=models.CharField("Quantity on Hand",max_length=30)
    product_status=models.CharField(max_length=15,choices=product_statuss, default='Available' )
```

Answer (score 2):

You have syntax error, should be

```
product=request.GET.get('product')
quantity=request.GET.get('quantity')
```

instead of

```
product=request.GET.get['product']
quantity=request.GET.get['quantity']
```

This is the reason why:

```
try:
    ...
except:
    ...
```

without specifying error type is very bad idea. You cannot say what error actually occured in your code.

Also[`render_to_response`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#render-to-response) is deprecated and you should use `render` instead of it:

```
return render(request, 'product/productlocation.html',{'product_result' : product_result,'quantity_result':quantity_result, 'product': product,'quantity':quantity})
```

Comment: actuly i want to checkquantity on hands field when user enter product and quantity then query ilter to check quantity_on hand is less then the user request if less then show out of stock else stock available

Comment: @rabia if you add `print(quantity_result)` to your productsearch function, can you see the result? Probaly queryset return nothing for entered value.

Comment: @rabia and did you see results in console? also replace render_to_response with render.

Comment: yeahh .. it gives me integer value 87

Comment: ? sir what to do i still didn't figure out the problem

Comment: @rabia sorry I dont see any problems.

Comment: its give me integer value which is not the value in database